# mysql order by two columns with singular standard

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two simple columns as this fiddle [Sql fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c98789)

I would this order:

```
    id   rev
    ==========
    1     1
    2     3
    6     3
    3     1
    4     2
   10     2
    5     1
    7     1
    8     1
    9     1
```

i want order by with column 'id', but if 'id'=2 then next must be 'id' with same 'rev' value.

It is possible?

[EDIT] Excuse me, i modified the fiddler...

[EDIT 25/10]
I tried to edit my query with @P.Salmon answer when id of first table is 'militare'.
But there is an error

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'rev' in 'field list'

```
SELECT 
    `militari`.`ordine` militare, 
    `ordini_servizio_dati`.`id_pattuglia` rev, 
    `ordini_servizio_dati`.`oggetto_servizio`, 
    `ordini_servizio_dati`.`luogo`, 
    `ordini_servizio_dati`.`orario`, 
    `ordini_servizio_dati`.`aut_orario`, 
    `ordini_servizio_dati`.`siris` 
FROM 
    `ordini_servizio_inizializzati`, 
    (
        select 
            militare, 
            rev, 
            if(rev <> @p, @rn := 1, @rn := @rn + 1) rn, 
            if(
                rev <> @p, @min := militare, @min := @min
            ) minid, 
            @p := rev p 
        from 
            `ordini_servizio_dati`, 
            (
                select 
                    @min := 0, 
                    @rn := 0, 
                    @p := 0
            ) r 
        order by 
            rev, 
            militare
    ) s 
    LEFT JOIN `schedario`.`ordini_servizio_dati` ON `ordini_servizio_inizializzati`.`id` = `ordini_servizio_dati`.`id_ordine` 
    LEFT JOIN `schedario`.`militari` ON `ordini_servizio_dati`.`militare` = `militari`.`matricola` 
WHERE 
    (
        `ordini_servizio_inizializzati`.`id` = '1'
    ) 
order by 
    case when rev = 1 then militare else minid end, 
    rn
```

Comment: What's the logic for this?

Comment: can you explain the order? I can't see the rules for `ORDER BY`!

Comment: _"I would this order:"_ - based on _what_? Supplying an sqlfiddle alone is not gonna help, if you don't explain at all what this order is supposed to be based on. Plus, the `rev` column in your fiddle contains three `2`, and only one `3`. And not even the association between `id` and `rev` is the same as in your expected example output ...?

Comment: i want order by with column 'id', but if 'id'=2 then next  must be 'id' with same 'rev' value.

Comment: can you write expected result based on your given value?

Comment: Excuse me  @LokeshKumarGaurav  i modified the fiddler...

Comment: @CBroe excuse me, i modified the fiddler!

Comment: Please add the expected output as well as the query you've tried so far into your question.

Comment: i did it @Harshil

Comment: Since id is not unique. then how do you now abut next coming row?

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav the fiddler is a example, however in my database 'id' is a primary key.

Comment: I'm unable to see the output or query in the question.

Comment: can you share your exact create query for the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic doesn't make sense given your data and what you have said I would expect output like this

```
+----+-----+
| id | rev |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |
|  3 |   1 |
|  5 |   1 |
|  7 |   1 |
|  8 |   1 |
|  9 |   1 |
|  2 |   3 |
|  6 |   3 |
|  4 |   2 |
| 10 |   2 |
+----+-----+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

or if you treat rev 1 as a special case you can

```
select id,rev
        #case when rev = 1 then id 
        #else minid 
        #end  as overwrite
from
(
select id,rev,
         if(rev<>@p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
         if(rev<>@p,@min:=id,@min:=@min) minid,
         @p:=rev p
from docs, (select @min:=0, @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by rev,id
) s
order by        case when rev = 1 then id 
        else minid 
        end  ,
            rn
```

Result

```
+----+-----+
| id | rev |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   3 |
|  6 |   3 |
|  3 |   1 |
|  4 |   2 |
| 10 |   2 |
|  5 |   1 |
|  7 |   1 |
|  8 |   1 |
|  9 |   1 |
+----+-----+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: If I asked here it is just because I can not. I want 'id' column ordered, but with my standard. I do not understand if it is the insecurity of my english or what...

Comment: There isn't a clear rule for getting the result you want, you have stated i want order by with column 'id', but if 'id'=2 then next must be 'id' with same 'rev' value but that seems also to apply for rev 1 and 3 and there is no obvious reason for rev 1 and rev 3 to behave any differently to rev 2. This is not a comment about code it's purely about logic.

Comment: Please see edit where rev 1 is treated as a special case.